# generating k prime numbers using Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: java, algorithm, primes

Looked through a few implementation and found, wondering why start iteration from k = m * m is safe? Thanks.

http://www.algolist.net/Algorithms/Number_theoretic/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

```
public void runEratosthenesSieve(int upperBound) {
      int upperBoundSquareRoot = (int) Math.sqrt(upperBound);
      boolean[] isComposite = new boolean[upperBound + 1];
      for (int m = 2; m <= upperBoundSquareRoot; m++) {
            if (!isComposite[m]) {
                  System.out.print(m + " ");
                  for (int k = m * m; k <= upperBound; k += m)
                        isComposite[k] = true;
            }
      }
      for (int m = upperBoundSquareRoot; m <= upperBound; m++)
            if (!isComposite[m])
                  System.out.print(m + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take a number and factorize it: eg. 120

- 1 x 120
- 2 x 60
- 3 x 40
- 4 x 30
- 5 x 24
- 6 x 20
- 8 x 15
- 10 x 12

Now, one observation: sqrt(120) = 11 (taking floor)

Now, next observation, `each of the above factors have one thing in common, ie. one of the factors is less than 11 and other is greater than 11`.

Now lets factorize 36:

- 1 x 36
- 2 x 18
- 3 x 12
- 4 x 9
- 6 x 6

and sqrt(36) = 6. Again we can do a similar observation, that, each one of the factors have one number less than 6 and other greater, except `6 x 6`, since 36 is a square.

So, we can easily deduce this:

> For any number, if it is not a prime number, we can always find (at least) one of its factor, if we go to its square root.

So, to reduce complexity, we need to go till the square root of every number in the range, so, `sqrt(upperBound)` is enough for outer loop. That is because, if any number is not marked composite by then, it will never be because we have considered all possible divisors that can be.

EDIT:

Also, this implementation of sieve is not `most optimized` that can be. Not in terms of asymptotic complexity, but you can do things to reduce few operations. I'll add my implementation of sieve in c++, which calculates all primes till MAX.

```
#define MAX 1000000
#define I int
#define FOR(i,a,b) for(i=a;i<b;i++)
I p[MAX]={1,1,0};            //global declaration
I prime[MAX/10]={2};         //global declaration
void sieve()
{
    I i,j,k=1;
    for(i=3;i*i<=MAX;i+=2)
    {
        if(p[i])
            continue;
        for(j=i*i;j<MAX;j+=2*i)
            p[j]=1;
    }
    for(i = 3; i < MAX; i+=2)
    {
        if(!p[i])
            prime[k++]=i;
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: I think that the question was actually asking about where the iteration to set the iscomposite flags is started (it starts at m*m each iteration, rather than simply at m), rather than how we know we've done enough to ensure that a number is prime.

Comment: @moreON, good catch. I understand as a factor of a number n, if it is larger than sqrt(n), there must be a pair factor whose value is less than sqrt(n), but I do now know why prime number should also less than sqrt(n), any guidance is appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thanks vish4071, if you could comment on my above question, it will be great -- I understand as a factor of a number n, if it is larger than sqrt(n), there must be a pair factor whose value is less than sqrt(n), but I do now know why prime number should also less than sqrt(n), any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Prime numbers will be greater than sqrt(n), but they don't need to be flagged after outer loop goes beyond sqrt(n). (n = upperBound), because, all the composite numbers above sqrt(n) are already flagged. So, they are all wasteful iterations.

Comment: This clearly means, if any number above sqrt(n) is not flagged, *it is a prime number*.

Comment: Thanks vish4071, how do you know "all the composite numbers above sqrt(n) are already flagged"?

Comment: This is because, for *every* composite number, we have at least one of its factors which we have already encountered. (Because a least one factor will be below sqrt(n) ). So, that factor *will definitely* have flagged that number as composite (through the inner loop). If a number was not flagged composite by any number, *it is a prime number*

Comment: if you consider a composite number, a\*b, where a >= b >= n, then clearly a\*b >= n\*n. So any number that has a pair of factors where both are larger than n, is clearly above n\*n, so any number less than n\*n is either prime or has at least one factor less than n.

Comment: Thanks @moreON, for each outer loop, we find one number which is not marked as composite and use it to sieve other numbers. The question is, how do we know the number which is not marked must be a prime number? Thanks.

Comment: @vish4071, if you could comment on my above question, "for each outer loop, we find one number which is not marked as composite and use it to sieve other numbers. The question is, how do we know the number which is not marked must be a prime number", it will be great. Thanks for all the guidance in advance. :)

Comment: @LinMa, because, if it were a composite number, we would have encountered at least one of its factors and it would have marked it composite (through inner loop). So, if a number is not marked, it is prime. I don't know which part of this you are not able to understand.

Comment: @vish4071, thanks for the clarification, I think when we evaluate number m, if it is a composite, we should be able to reach it by its factor less than sqrt(m), which should be less than sqrt(n). So wondering if we could change from sqrt(n) to sqrt(m) to make the algorithm more efficient? Thanks.

Comment: In that case, results for primes would be incorrect. Because `n` is upper bound, sqrt(n) is upper bound for sqrt(i), 1<i<=n, but `m (<n)` would not provide square root bound for other numbers in the range. Also, we are not evaluating any number individually in sieve, it is always a range.

Comment: @vish4071, what do you mean "but m (<n) would not provide square root bound for other numbers in the range", more insights are appreciated.

Comment: your range (1...10^6).Say you choose m = 10000. Then, sqrt(m) = 100, which is insufficient to confirm primality of numbers above 10000 in your range (in which you have to calculate primes), like 99997 etc. But sqrt(10^6) = 1000, which is greater than sqrt(99997), and so primality of 99997 *will* be checked.

Answer (score 3):

Every composite number less than m*m that m is a factor of, eg. m*n, has a smaller factor than m, eg. n, for which we have already marked it as composite.

This works for prime or composite n, for prime n, we set during the cycle when m=n.

For composite n: We know that any integer > 1 is representable as a product of prime factors. One of these prime factors is the smallest prime factor of n, we'll call this s. Since s is a prime factor of n, we can express n as s*r, for some r. This also means that m*n is m*s*r. s < m as n < m and s < n. We know that r has no prime factors smaller than s, as it was defined this way. So s must be be the smallest prime factor of m*s*r, so we set its iscomposite flag during the cycle for m=s

Comment: I think in this case, n * m is evaluated as long as n is prime? Or whatever n is (composite or prime)?

Comment: If n is composite, then n \* m would have been marked when the smallest prime factor of n was used.

Comment: Thanks moreON, you mean suppose n = pow (p1, x1) * pow (p2, x2), both p1 and p2 are < n and also < m which should be evaluated by either p1 or p2?

Comment: I've edited to provide a more general explanation of this for composite n.